# Inexact search by comparing all letters/numbers in a varchar. mysql, php

Tags: php, mysql

So what I have is a database of model numbers. What I need to happen is if the model number stored is "`ABCD1234`" and the user searches "`BCD123`" it will still return the result. Using "`like`" works for me if the database entry contains the searched model # at the beginning or the end, but i need something that will return a result anytime the database entry contains the searched numbers.
 Thank you!

Comment: did you try to envelope search text with %? example ... SELECT * FROM table WHERE model LIKE '%BCD123%';

Comment: as easy as that.. thanks! If you would like to put this as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Envelope the search text with % like:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE model LIKE '%BCD123%';